# Understanding the datasource logs of weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I have my application running on weblogic server where I have configured a JNDI data-source for getting database connection. I am trying to understand the datasource logs which are generated by the weblogic server.

Path: `$MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/my_domain/servers/TestManagedServer/logs/datasource.logxxxxx`

Log content:

```
####<testdb> <WEBLOGIC.JDBC.CONN.MT_USAGE> <Fri Feb 14 04:57:20 PST 2014> <java.lang.Exception
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.setup(ConnectionEnv.java:356)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:364)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:330)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:469)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:363)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:125)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:158)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:132)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getNonTxConnection(Driver.java:658)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:127)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:533)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:498)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:491)
```

It looks like there is an error message but I am not able to understand why the data-source is giving errors. Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: If you copy the content of the jdbc.xml file from my domain/config/jdbc I could tell if you made something obviously wrong with the configuration

Comment: You can log in to the weblogic admin console, click your DataSource, click the Monitoring tab and then try to Test the connection. The resulting log may give additional info

Comment: My interpretation is that this is a stacktrace where te connection where retrieved and non really an error. Did you come to any conclusions on this?

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to tell from log content.
`WEBLOGIC.JDBC.CONN.MT_USAGE` indicates multi-threaded usage.  You can enable profiling and debug monitoring. The WebLogic docs here show how:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/monitor.htm

There some JDBC debugging tips here as well:

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2477
http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=586